# Chip with react-router Link

Tags: material-ui

[Chip](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/chip/) gives possibility to generate a link using `component="a" clickable href="/"`, but I can't find a way to generate it as a react-router `<Link>`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way, it needs to have both `component` and `to` parameters, not `href`

```
<Chip
   key={tag.slug}
   label={tag.translation}
   component={Link}
   to={"/tag/" + tag.slug}
   clickable
/>
```